# Tuning required for Kafka Streams Application

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a kafka streams application which reads from one topic with 100 partitions. Does some stateless transformations on individual messages and produces it to another topic. There are 2 instances of the application running on 2 machines with 4 cores and 8Gb ram, `num.stream.threads` is configured to 50. The throughput for output topic is very low. What are the tunining parameters to look at for increasing the processing speed of the Kafka Stream Application.

[image]

Comment: Please try to specify, what you did so far to retrieve data. Maybe some Code?

Comment: @DaGroove Data is consumed from input topic using StreamsBuilder.stream method. Is that what you were asking for?

Comment: If your machines have only 4 cores, it would be better to run with only 4 threads per machine -- or maybe 8. This should utilize all cores fully already. Having more thread will actually slow down your application. Also, how many partitions does you output topic have?

Comment: Output topic also has 100 partitions. Also, reducing threads, the CPU goes under utilised. Application is hardly utilising above 20% per core.

Comment: Were you able to find good tuning parameters for Kafka Streams?

Comment: @ammills01 ended up increasing the number of stream app nodes to 10 and creating a topic with 10 partitions. The number of tasks is set to 1. So there is a total of 10 tasks.  1 task running per node. The consumption rate now comes to around 8k

Comment: I have an app running in Java, using the Processor API not DSL, and with just a simple source -> sink move I can get throughput rates of at least 20k per minute (12 partitions in this topic).  When I introduce a processor with very limited functionality that drops significantly.  Bumping the num.stream.threads helps, or running lots of instances, but not much more.  I do know that having 100 partitions caused me pain with Spark in the past, keeping track of checkpoints was expensive on a small cluster.